# How enable JS onchange event for HTML grid cell

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to use JQuery - just HTML and JS

I have an HTML grid and I want to detect DOM 'onchange' TextArea changes in cells that make up a specific column of the grid.

I'm not sure how to register that 'onchange' function to be called - can someone help?

More info ----

Currently - I have a small embedded micro that offers web pages for configuration.  I use Jquery and a small JQ grid editor.

I want to get rid of JQ since the code size is 20 times larger than my application pages.  When I get rid of JQ -- I also get rid of the small grid editor.

I do not use HTML Forms.

I dynamically create the grid based on the configuration data.  A typical grid  might be 6 columns and 15 rows.

I want to validate a user entry in a cell 'onchange' in a specific column so my JS code update/modify the other cells in the grid based on that change.

Here is the HTML page entry for the grid

```
       <div class="UnivTable">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Universes</legend>
      <table id="tblUniverses" >
        <tr>
          <th>Order<br />Placement</th>
          <th style="width:10px"></th>
          <th>Universe<br />Number</th>
          <th>Channels<br />per Universe</th>
          <th style="width:10px"></th>
          <th style="display:none;"></th>
          <th>Controller<br />Start Channel</th>
          <th>Controller<br />End Channel</th>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Here is my current JQ for adding a ROW

```
         $("#tblUniverses tbody").append(
     "<tr>"+
     "<td>"+DA[0]+"</td>"+
     "<td class='gap'></td>"+       
     "<td contenteditable='true'>"+DA[1]+"</td>"+
     "<td contenteditable='true'>"+DA[2]+"</td>"+
     "<td class='gap'></td>"+
     "<td style='display:none;'>"+DA[3]+"</td>"+
     "<td class='NF'>"+DA[4]+"</td>"+
     "<td class='NF'>"+DA[5]+"</td>"+       
     "</tr>");
```

THAT will be changed to JS code.

There are two (2) cells in THAT row that I want to fire an event on.

Can I add a listener within the    statement?

Do I loop thru the DOM for that table and all an event listener for those cells - if so how?

Comment: show the code please :)

Comment: I the grid a static HTML or is it build dynamically, form JS?

Comment: Are you having trouble selecting the correct DOM element/s? or attaching the event listener?

Comment: If you want to register if it is called, why not use console.log('Hello') inside the onchange function?

Comment: When you are asking questions related to your projects always share your code So that it will be easy for us to help specifically in resolving that problem.

Comment: I added more info.  I don't know how to add the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

HTML example

```
<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>
<div id="log"></div>
```

that script help to you

```
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
            const log = document.getElementById('log');

       textarea.addEventListener('change' , updateValue)
       function updateValue(e) {
           console.log(e);
           log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
});
```

you can hang listener through id change
and write your own function in which anything can be.
Through e you can track what you can change on your page

Comment: I can't see how to apply your answer to my question.  You answered based on my incomplete question - which since you posted I explained my question further.